# How to set visible="true" for gridview by javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have usercontrol for gridview.
I have made GridView visible="false".
When i click on a button it should be displayed.
Here is my code but im getting error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showGrid() {
        alert("calling function");
        document.getElementById("<%= GridView1.ClientID%>").visibility = 'visible';
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="btnView" runat="server" OnClientClick="showGrid();" BackColor="Blue" BorderStyle="None" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" Text="Show Grid" />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" ClientIDMode="Static" **Visible="false"**
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" 
    BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical">
```

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object

Comment: If you set `Visible="false"`, the grid isn't even sent to the browser, so you can't just set the visibility with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

using Jquery you can do

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#GridView1').css('visibility','visible');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
   document.getElementById('GridView1').style.visibility = 'visible';

Comment: it gives the following error : "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required"

Answer (score 0):

How about putting your Grid View inside a div and use some simple JQuery like:

```
$('YourDivID').hide();
```